# JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to create forget password script for my app .When i run my apk and try to rest my password i got error which says Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error, Everything is working fine in my apk i can login and logout or register but when i reset password i got JsonReader.setLenient(true) error. My apk json is working and it's correct. Please Help me. I'm Sharing my code.

```
{
   "operation":"resPassReq",
   "user":{
       "email":"name@example.com"

   }
}
```

and if the request is sucess the response would be similar to,

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "Check your mail for reset password code."
}
```

For finishing password reset process the request would be similar to,

```
{
   "operation":"resPass",
   "user":{
       "email":"name@example.com",
       "code":"bcfqa3",
       "password":"rjamalw"

   }
}
```

and if the request is success the response would be similar to,

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "Password Changed Successfully"
}
```

ResetPasswordFragment.java

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ResetPasswordFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private AppCompatButton btn_reset;
    private EditText et_email,et_code,et_password;
    private TextView tv_timer;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private boolean isResetInitiated = false;
    private String email;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_password_reset,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        btn_reset = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
        tv_timer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        et_code = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_code);
        et_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        et_password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_code.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn_reset.setOnClickListener(this);
        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn_reset:

                if(!isResetInitiated) {


                    email = et_email.getText().toString();
                    if (!email.isEmpty()) {
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        initiateResetPasswordProcess(email);
                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {

                    String code = et_code.getText().toString();
                    String password = et_password.getText().toString();

                    if(!code.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){

                        finishResetPasswordProcess(email,code,password);
                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_INITIATE);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    et_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    et_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    et_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_reset.setText("Change Password");
                    isResetInitiated = true;
                    startCountdownTimer();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void finishResetPasswordProcess(String email,String code, String password){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setCode(code);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_FINISH);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    isResetInitiated = false;
                    goToLogin();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void startCountdownTimer(){
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv_timer.setText("Time remaining : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Snackbar.make(getView(), "Time Out ! Request again to reset password.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                goToLogin();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void goToLogin(){

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

RequestInterface.java

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @POST("req/")
    Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);

}
```

But When i change my code like below, Everything is working fine, but problem is that got response onFailure

```
private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_INITIATE);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    et_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    et_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    et_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_reset.setText("Change Password");
                    isResetInitiated = true;
                    startCountdownTimer();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
               // Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                et_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                et_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                et_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_reset.setText("Change Password");
                isResetInitiated = true;
                startCountdownTimer();
               // Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }

    private void finishResetPasswordProcess(String email,String code, String password){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setCode(code);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_FINISH);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    isResetInitiated = false;
                    goToLogin();

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
               // Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                isResetInitiated = false;
                goToLogin();

            }
        });
    }
```

ServerResponse.java

```
public class ServerResponse {

    private String result;
    private String message;
    private User user;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

ServerRequest.java

```
public class ServerRequest {

    private String operation;
    private User user;

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should share the error you get. You can print it by replacing ```Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");``` with ```Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed",t);``` in the onFailure callbacks. You may also want to output whatever relevant information the ```call``` object contains.

Comment: i got this error - JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error

Comment: Well, obviously the API is not returning json when you reset your password

Comment: Please tell, how can I solve it..

Comment: you can try this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path

Comment: i am getting this error at compile time how can i solve it no any response change then also get this error at compile time

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem and finally, I solved it.

You have to make all $row in your API as the same name in the table on the database, like this

```
    "book_chalet_id" => $row['book_chalet_id'],
```

so in the table must has column `book_chalet_id`.

Comment: These do not need to be the same, it's just encouraged to

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                           .setLenient()
                           .create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
            request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_INITIATE);
            request.setUser(user);
            Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

            response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                    ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        et_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        et_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        et_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn_reset.setText("Change Password");
                        isResetInitiated = true;
                        startCountdownTimer();

                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                   // Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    et_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    et_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    et_password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_reset.setText("Change Password");
                    isResetInitiated = true;
                    startCountdownTimer();
                   // Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });
        }

        private void finishResetPasswordProcess(String email,String code, String password){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                           .setLenient()
                           .create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setCode(code);
            user.setPassword(password);
            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
            request.setOperation(Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_FINISH);
            request.setUser(user);
            Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

            response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                    ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        isResetInitiated = false;
                        goToLogin();

                    } else {

                        Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                   // Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    isResetInitiated = false;
                    goToLogin();

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: After editing it i got another error -> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Give ServerResponse class code also in the question. Now, this is json parsing error.

Comment: I have Added ServResponse class.

Comment: In which function you are getting this error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ and what's that response

Comment: private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email)

Comment: And what json response is returning?

Comment: Json is not returning. I got failed, in my Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed"); tag.

Comment: Debug your app by placing breakpoint on that line, and check the value of t of onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t).

Comment: i got it by debuging email = "myemail@gmail.com"
this = {ResetPasswordFragment@831728018520} "ResetPasswordFragment{536d322c #0 id=0x7f0c006d}"

Comment: I think whatever the input needed for API is not satisfying or may be server error. If you are got your asked question's answer, then please, upvote the answer.

Comment: Try to check the API by using POSTMAN REST API Client. There you will get to know what input you are entering and the response. Depending on that you will get the idea what things need to change in the code.

Comment: Can you post input JSON string needed for the API

Comment: Can you give what input JSON string needed for the API. Also, try by adding @Headers("Content-Type: application/json") in the interface method

Comment: i have added {
   "operation":"resPassReq",
   "user":{
       "email":"name@example.com"

   }
} in postman than i got {
  "result": "success",
  "message": "Check your mail for reset password code."
}

Comment: i have added @Headers("Content-Type: application/json") but it's not working

Comment: i have got email from my server but on my app message show failed.

Comment: Another point is that everything is working on localhost but on my Godaddy server it's now working.. i got JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error

Comment: Convert your ServerRequest object to string using Gson and print that string in the Log. And for malformed JSON you should set gson setlenient property to true while using GsonConvertorFactory as i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Do you understand malformed JSON error solution? And in private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email) before Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);     Add this code Gson gson = new Gson(); String s = gson.toJson(request); Log.d("request data",s);

Comment: Not understood malformed JSON ERROR solution

Comment: For malformed JSON ERROR solution, updated the answer.

Comment: For another problem, in private void initiateResetPasswordProcess(String email) before Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request); Add this code Gson gson = new Gson(); String s = gson.toJson(request); Log.d("request data",s); AND let me know the logs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133545/discussion-on-answer-by-mdg5435-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed).

Comment: Thank you for moving. Looking for it.

Comment: got error JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error

Comment: You should really explain your answer in smaller pieces than only provide a block of code

Comment: Another Error after put your codes - > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Share your JSON data

Comment: {
   "operation":"resPassReq",
   "user":{
       "email":"name@example.com"

   }
}

Comment: Have you checked Retrofit Logs in the Log trace? May be there you will get to know your API url, passed data.

Comment: You haven't got the solution for your problem till now ?

Comment: Is this answer correct? is it accepted? i am facing same issue. and the main problem I am facing is that on my testing device I'm not facing this issue, but when i release it to playstore and check fabric I see 1000 crashes. It is really causing problem. How do i solve this?

Comment: @Parth, while adding GsonConverterFactory to Retrofit's ConverterFactory pass gson object with setLenient property. (Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                           .setLenient()
                           .create();)

Answer (score -2):

resolver this error for uploading Image with Retrofit 2 in android:JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ Error

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode ==10) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 10);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "you have dont Permisson", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```