# error from retrofit JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

Tags: android, json

i know this question ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path) but i can not able to solve it the same error are come . some of my web service are work fine but some of my web service are showing this error . follwing is my base url code .

ServiceGenerators

```
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myurl.com/";
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    public static <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceClass) {

        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();

        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

follwing is my json responses first  response is working and second is not working
Working responses

```
    {
  "status": "success",
  "records": [
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "12",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-15",
      "report_time": "03:01:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "120",
      "diastolic": "50"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "14",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-16",
      "report_time": "07:27:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "120",
      "diastolic": "80"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "15",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-17",
      "report_time": "07:28:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "140",
      "diastolic": "100"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "16",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-18",
      "report_time": "07:28:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "160",
      "diastolic": "120"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "17",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-19",
      "report_time": "07:29:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "135",
      "diastolic": "85"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "18",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-20",
      "report_time": "07:29:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "137",
      "diastolic": "99"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "19",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-21",
      "report_time": "07:29:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "148",
      "diastolic": "121"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "20",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-22",
      "report_time": "07:30:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "115",
      "diastolic": "110"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "21",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-23",
      "report_time": "07:30:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "129",
      "diastolic": "90"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "22",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-03-24",
      "report_time": "07:31:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "168",
      "diastolic": "108"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "25",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "103",
      "report_date": "2017-03-26",
      "report_time": "01:26:00",
      "person": "aaq",
      "systolic": "120",
      "diastolic": "250"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "28",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "report_date": "2017-07-08",
      "report_time": "01:24:00",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "systolic": "90",
      "diastolic": "90"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "32",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "113",
      "report_date": "0000-00-00",
      "report_time": "00:00:16",
      "person": "Sushil",
      "systolic": "120",
      "diastolic": "320"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "33",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "113",
      "report_date": "0000-00-00",
      "report_time": "00:00:16",
      "person": "Sushil",
      "systolic": "111",
      "diastolic": "211"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "34",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "113",
      "report_date": "0000-00-00",
      "report_time": "00:00:16",
      "person": "Sushil",
      "systolic": "100",
      "diastolic": "140"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "35",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "113",
      "report_date": "0000-00-00",
      "report_time": "00:00:16",
      "person": "Sushil",
      "systolic": "120",
      "diastolic": "1340"
    },
    {
      "bloodpressure_id": "36",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "113",
      "report_date": "0000-00-00",
      "report_time": "00:00:17",
      "person": "Sushil",
      "systolic": "1111",
      "diastolic": "5555"
    }
  ]
}
```

Not working response

```
 {
  "status": "success",
  "records": [
    {
      "measurements_id": "24",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "report_date": "2017-07-01",
      "report_time": "05:30:00",
      "record_name": "aaaaq",
      "record_details": "asda ads ad"
    },
    {
      "measurements_id": "25",
      "user_id": "73",
      "relative_id": "102",
      "person": "Lalit",
      "report_date": "2017-07-03",
      "report_time": "05:30:00",
      "record_name": "eeeq",
      "record_details": "cxvxv"
    }
  ]
}
```

the error messege

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 1 path $
```

class model
measurementsListing

```
    public class measurementsListing {

    String status;
    List<ReportAndMeasurementsModel> records;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<ReportAndMeasurementsModel> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<ReportAndMeasurementsModel> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }


}
```

ReportAndMeasurementsModel

```
 public class ReportAndMeasurementsModel {

    String ReportFor;
    String report_date;
    String report_time;
    String RecordName;
    String record_name;
    String Attachments;
    String measurements_id;
    String user_id;
    String relative_id;
    String record_details;

    public String getReport_date() {
        return report_date;
    }

    public void setReport_date(String report_date) {
        this.report_date = report_date;
    }

    public String getReport_time() {
        return report_time;
    }

    public void setReport_time(String report_time) {
        this.report_time = report_time;
    }

    public String getRecord_name() {
        return record_name;
    }

    public void setRecord_name(String record_name) {
        this.record_name = record_name;
    }

    public String getMeasurements_id() {
        return measurements_id;
    }

    public void setMeasurements_id(String measurements_id) {
        this.measurements_id = measurements_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getRelative_id() {
        return relative_id;
    }

    public void setRelative_id(String relative_id) {
        this.relative_id = relative_id;
    }

    public String getRecord_details() {
        return record_details;
    }

    public void setRecord_details(String record_details) {
        this.record_details = record_details;
    }

    public ReportAndMeasurementsModel(String mReportFor, String mDate, String mTime, String mRecordName, String mRecordDetails, String mattachment) {


        this.ReportFor=mReportFor;
        this.report_date=mDate;
        this.report_time=mTime;
        this.RecordName=mRecordName;
        this.record_name=mRecordDetails;
        this.Attachments=mattachment;
    }

    public String getReportFor() {
        return ReportFor;
    }

    public void setReportFor(String reportFor) {
        ReportFor = reportFor;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return report_date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        report_date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return report_time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        report_time = time;
    }

    public String getRecordName() {
        return RecordName;
    }

    public void setRecordName(String recordName) {
        RecordName = recordName;
    }

    public String getRecordDetails() {
        return record_name;
    }

    public void setRecordDetails(String recordDetails) {
        record_name = recordDetails;
    }

    public String getAttachments() {
        return Attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(String attachments) {
        Attachments = attachments;
    }



}
```

any help is welcome

Comment: add your class model

Comment: where i add class medel?

Comment: post here source code of your class model that you use to parse json

Comment: posted the class model

Comment: also ReportAndMeasurementsModel please

Comment: ReportAndMeasurementsModel added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152148/discussion-between-kunal-nikam-and-an-droid-dev).