# JasonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ error

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

my app keeps returning "use `JasonReader.setLenient(true)` to accept malformed `JSON` at line 1 column 1 path $" when I try to register a user. I have gone through most of the questions relating to this but none has really helped me. below is the register process that initiates the connection to server.

```
 private void registerProcess( final String name,final String email,final String password){

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";
    //pDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("please wait");
    pDialog.show();

          Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);
    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        private View view;

        public View getView() {
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();

           // if(resp !=null)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

           // progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.dismiss();


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you read this link : [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is the response at first. I think you are getting collection of json objects but you are trying to convert it to a single object. Make sure your response is a single json object or if you have json array response then tune up your code. Your code will actually work for single json object.

Comment: please how can I do that