# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 -Retrofit

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

i'm using retrofit for my project. when i try to access my webservice,in onFailure i'm getting `JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $` on LogCat.i can get response from POSTMAN

this is postman response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "order status updated"
}
```

OnCreate **Update**

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("https://example.com/sample/")                    
                            .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();
        token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9";
        id_order= 288;
        status="process";
        update();
```

Method

```
public void update(){
        WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
        Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call = apiService.updateOrder("pickorder",token,id_order,status);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateOrderResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call, Response<UpdateOrderResponse> response) {

                UpdateOrderResponse result = response.body();
                Log.d("orderstatus", "body: "+result);
                returnstatus=result.isStatus();
                msg= result.getMessage();

                if(returnstatus){
                    Log.d("orderstatus","status ok");
                }else{
                    Log.d("orderstatus","status not ok");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("proceedFail",""+t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
```

PHP service response

```
$response = ['status' => true,
        'message' => "order status updated",
         ];
$this->returnJson($response);
```

UpdateOrderResponse Module class

```
public class UpdateOrderResponse {
    boolean status;
    String message;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }    
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }    
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**Update**

i have added `gson.setLenient()` to retrofit.like below

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com/sample/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

then got another error on `onFailure` it is `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1`. i have also added `HttpLoggingInterceptor` and checked my LogCat.it showing me

```
OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://........
OkHttp: {"status":true,"message":"order status updated"}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (99-byte body)    
proceedFail: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsonReader.setLinent(true) error retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path).. check the solution given here

Comment: i have followed that answer.then i got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1`.now i have no idea how to convert my String response to Object

Comment: please go through the whole answer which include the answer for your next error..Add HttpLoggingInterceptor to log the response you are getting from server and then compare with your model

Comment: i have added `HttpLoggingInterceptor`.but nothing showing in LogCat.also i have updated my post

Comment: Paste your UpdateOrderResponse model, it seems you are returning array from php response ..correct me if I'm wrong bcz I don't know php

Comment: Php webservice response is object.it's response is top on my question (POSTMAN response ).

Comment: then please add a break point and debug the response

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Even though I don't have any idea of php..i would recommend altering your response..instead of returnjson try using json_encode refer : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GSON to parse your response, we need to use @SerializedName and @Expose tags in the model class.
Please replace your UpdateOrderResponse with below code:

```
public class UpdateOrderResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have replace my model class with your code.but same error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: If the keys and variable names are same then  no need to explicitly mention SerializedName.