# ApolloParseException : failed to parse http response

Tags: java, android, graphql, apollo-client

making a graphql call using Apolloclient-Android:

```
apolloClient().mutate(RegisterCardTokenMutation.builder().token(token).build()).enqueue(object : ApolloCall.Callback<RegisterCardTokenMutation.Data>() {
                override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                    emitter.onError(e)
                }

                override fun onResponse(response: Response<RegisterCardTokenMutation.Data>) {
                    emitter.onNext((response.data() as RegisterCardTokenMutation.Data).registerCreditCard())
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }
            })
```

here is the apollo client.

```
  private fun apolloClient(): ApolloClient =
                ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .okHttpClient(OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                                    val original = chain.request()
                                    val builder = original.newBuilder().method(original.method(), original.body())
                                    builder.header("Authorization", "TOKEN")
                                    chain.proceed(builder.build())
                                }
                                .build())
                        .addCustomTypeAdapter(CustomType.TOKEN, customTypeAdapter.tokenCustomAdapter)
                        .build()
```

Always shows the error :[image]

What might be wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path/40013869

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @MuM6oJuM6o add httpLogger to be sure of the response you are receiving.

Comment: please look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683846/3598837

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue making a graphql call from android-client

I solved it by removing the all the Dates types (createAt, updatedAt, etc) from my graphql queries.

Also, if you have to added "_id" to your gradle dependencies remove the _id build and then run

You can also follow official apollo-android document to add custom scalar types https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#custom-scalar-types

It should work perfectly