# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. - Android Studio Error

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I'm having trouble using **Firebase authenticatio**n in conjunction with **FirebaseUI**. When I run my application the following problem appears: "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp (Context) first."

In my app / build.gradle I have the dependencies:

```
     implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-auth: 16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-database: 16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.firebaseui: firebase-ui-auth: 4.1.0'
```

and the `"apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services"` at the end.

in my module / build.gradle I have dependency:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.1.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'
```

I have already exported my googleservices.json to the "app" folder. I was left with no options and the problem continues. Any suggestions?

Logcat:

--------- beginning of crash

```
08-31 19:40:12.718 2865-2865/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.luccas.buscaperto, PID: 2865
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.luccas.buscaperto/br.com.luccas.buscaperto.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process br.com.luccas.buscaperto. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process br.com.luccas.buscaperto. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.luccas.buscaperto.MainActivity.instantiateUser(MainActivity.java:89)
        at br.com.luccas.buscaperto.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my top level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        release = [
                versionName: "6.1.0-rc01",
                versionCode: 6100
        ]

        setup = [
                compileSdk: 28,
                buildTools: "28.0.2",
                minSdk    : 14,
                targetSdk : 28
        ]

        versions = [
                androidX: '1.0.0-rc01'
        ]
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

my app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.luccas.buscaperto"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:${versions.androidX}"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.0-rc01'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${versions.androidX}"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like so:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0
```

And change this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Comment: if I remove the "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07", I get the error: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: I didn't say to remove it but to change it to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` Have you tried this approach?

Comment: I'm using both: 
`classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.1.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'`

Comment: No, you need to use only one, the one from my last comment. Does it work this way?

Comment: then it says: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: In this case update the gradle in your top level `build.gradle` file to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'` Does it work now?

Comment: I edited the question and attached the build.gradle files

Comment: Remove this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'` and add  this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`. Does it work?

Comment: Failed to resolve: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.0.0-rc01

Comment: I see that you get now another error, which means that basically the inital error disappeared. So your initial problem is now solved. Good to hear that :-)  The fact that you are getting now another error should not scare you but this sound as another question. My personal hint is to comment that line of code and add this `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`.

Comment: If my above hint doesn't solve the second problem, in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the help

Comment: Actualy I downgraded de version to " classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'" and it works!

Comment: I recommend you always use the latest versions but if you say it worked, these are good news, cheers!

Comment: @AlexMamo you are mixing Gradle Build Tools and Google Services Plugin which both does totally different things and later recommend use an old version of build tools... You should check what which do: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin :)

Comment: @mtrakal Oh ya, you're right, my mistake. It should be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`. I have copied and paste the wrong line of code. Sorry about that. Just updated my answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo using 3.1.4 will not solve it when you work with AS 3.2 or 3.3 canary :). Using 3.1.4 is not possible too when you use Gradle 4.6+ :)

Comment: @mtrakal Why do you say that? I've tested with `3.3.0-alpha07` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Please upgrade your project level gms dependencies, I upgraded to **4.2.0** and it worked

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: I studied the release notes so found the dependencies of different versions

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and the issue was with google-services.json that was not in proper format and some how, google-services.json had following in the file

> COMMENT start
>   clone the project and in firefox create a database and give the package name as .....

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your google_services.json file. Download it from firebase and replace with  the existing one. In json file there is a configuration which automatically merged the content provider which intitalizes your Firebase for the app with your manifest by default on building with gradle. But your current json file is missing that configuration. So you need to replace or you need to call `static FirebaseApp(Context)` method to solve this problem.[Read Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp)

Add this in your app launcher onCreate method as

```
...... onCreate(.....)
       {
          FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
          ..........   

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by downgradind to:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my app,
but according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112716914 this issue tracker
I have updated to version classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` and issue got resolved.

Answer (score -2):

Edit your dependencies in build.gradle Project level:

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Oncreate method add this:

```
     FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```