# Can't upload code in real host with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My code in local host is working good but in real host get this error.

```
"Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"
```

When i add json to my code , it gives another error like this.

*"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"*

and this is my code :

```
public class ApiClient {


 private static final String BASE_URL = "http://aminkhataei.ir/android_login_api/";

  private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


  public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {


      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .create();


      retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }

}
```

and my model :

```
  public class MyResponse {
  @SerializedName("uid")
  private String uid;
  @SerializedName("error")
  private boolean error;
  @SerializedName("msg")
  private String msg;

  public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
  }



  public String getUid() {
    return uid;
  }


  public boolean isError() {
    return error;
  }

  public void setError(boolean error) {
    this.error = error;
  } 
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the response the live server is returning. Have a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418787/3809653).

Your endpoint is returning "jj" instead of JsonObject you are expecting.

Comment: jj is not important.just for test.how can do this in topic link?@ArbenMaloku

Comment: Have a look at this also [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013869/3809653)

Comment: I see this but I confused about structure in topic link@ArbenMaloku

Comment: Your server is sending you a string but you're accepting MyResponse. What do you not understand about this issue?

Comment: my respone like this: {"error":false,"uid":"5c13cc75a25978.01070617","user":{"name":"amin","created_at":"2018-12-14 18:59:57","updated_at":null,"email":"k@k.k"},"msg":"login !"} @ZUNJAE

Comment: _"My code in local host is working good"_ Okay fine. Did you test that API after hosting it in live server? Test it with Postman or any other REST API clients and confirm that it returns expected JSON data. I assume that API doesn't return proper JSON response after hosting.