# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ in kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to add data to Mysql via php party. But I keep failing. Check the data on the website. Still no solution. Where am I going wrong?

I tried the following and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.
[How to fix 'Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $' error in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336845/how-to-fix-use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-c) and [Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path)

I get another error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ from this error Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $. Adding GsonBuilder() .

I use //... to minimize the code.

dependencies

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    //... />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    //... />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    //... />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonInsert"
    //...
     />
```

MainActivity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        //...
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            //...
            binding.buttonInsert.setOnClickListener {
insert(editText1.text.toString(),editText2.text.toString(),editText3.text.toString())
            }
        }
    
        fun insert(name:String,alamal:String,telepon:String){
            val ardData:APIinsertData = InsertServer().konekRetrofit2()!!.create(APIinsertData::class.java)
            val tampilData: Call<ResponseModel?>? = ardData.insertData(name,alamal,telepon)
            tampilData?.enqueue(object :Callback<ResponseModel?>{
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ResponseModel?>,
                    response: Response<ResponseModel?>
                ) {
                    //...
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseModel?>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("ex","==${t.message.toString()}")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

interface APIinsertData

```
interface APIinsertData {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("insert.php")
    open fun insertData(
        @Field("name")name:String,
        @Field("alamal")alamal:String,
        @Field("telepon")telepon:String
    ): Call<ResponseModel?>?
}
```

InsertServer

```
class InsertServer {
    private val baseURL="http://10.0.2.2/insertData/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit?=null
    var gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    fun konekRetrofit2(): Retrofit? {
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit= Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
}
```

data class

```
data class DataModel (
    val id:Int,
    val name:String,
    val alamal:String,
    val telepon:String
        )
data class ResponseModel (
    val kode:Int,
    val pesan:String,
    val data:List<DataModel>
        )
```

The current simple information of MySql comes from response.body().

```
[DataModel(id=1, name=abc, alamal=cde, telepon=123),
 DataModel(id=4, name=adc, alamal=111, telepon=222)]
```

Comment: The vote reflects usefulness of the question. It has no relation to your education. Please note that Stack Overflow is like Wikipedia. This is not a free help desk. Please don't take votes personally. The vote on your post has no impact on your learning ability. Please take the [tour] to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This response come from your server `[DataModel(id=1, name=abc, alamal=cde, telepon=123), DataModel(id=4, name=adc, alamal=111, telepon=222)]`
so you set response serializable for api is wrong must be like this

```
interface APIinsertData {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("insert.php")
open fun insertData(
    @Field("name")name:String,
    @Field("alamal")alamal:String,
    @Field("telepon")telepon:String
): Call<List<DataModel>>?
}
```

change insertData response like above will work fine with you

Comment: Thank you. I tried your method. But I can't insert the data correctly. I only insert one DataModel data each time, it doesn't seem to be multiple data. My original mysql data is only two random creations. I don't want to add more Pen.

Comment: are you mean can send to server correctly? @LoveCing

Comment: I get onFailure() to give me Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.

Comment: Are used my code change for interface APIinsertData ?
so this failure come you expected come object but your server return array @LoveCing

Comment: I used your code change for interface APIinsertData. Then I fetched unsuccessfully it says Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.

Comment: Please run your request on postman and show me response api result from postman ?

Comment: you need this.Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id','name'.'alamal','telepon')VALUES(NULL,'','','')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertData\insert.php:8

Comment: <?php
include "connect.php";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$alamal=$_POST['alamal'];
$telepon=$_POST['telepon'];

$qry="INSERT INTO td1_laundry('id','name'.'alamal','telepon')VALUES(NULL,$name,$alamal,$telepon)";
mysqli_query($con,$qry);

?>

Comment: Thank you friend, although you didn't hit it right, you let me know there is postman, although it took me a while to understand it. But the key place to help find the problem is the php problem. Thank you very much friend.