# Retrofit Kotlin unable to create a working post request

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do a POST request using Retrofit but I'm unable to make it work. It does work on Postman. I specified the header "Content-Type: application/json" and set my "email" and "password" parameters in the body and it works well.

But it doesn't on Android. Here are my codes :

```
private fun login() {
    val user = User("test@gmail.com", "dsea2EcFI32\\\"af'xn")

    this.service.login(user).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                // TODO
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            // TODO
            println(t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

The request :

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/api/authentication/login")
    fun login(@Body body: User): Call<LoginResponse>
```

User model

```
data class User(val email: String, val password: String)
```

LoginResponse :

```
class LoginResponse {
   @SerializedName("user")
   val user : UserResponse? = null
}

class UserResponse {
   @SerializedName("id") val still : String = null
   @SerializedName("firstName") val running : String = null
   @SerializedName("lastName") val bicycle : String = null
   @SerializedName("email") val walking : String = null
   @SerializedName("token") val vehicle : String = null
}
```

In case the auth is a failure, the server sends me back an HTML page so the only error I have is

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I already set it to true and it keeps saying me that the GSON parsed object isn't a JSON object but I know there's an Android code here

Can someone helps me finding it ?

PS : I even tried to send the body as a JSON object but same error

PS2 : might this be due to the password even If I added enough backspace to accept the special characters ? the real string is **dsea2EcFI32"af'xn**

EDIT :

As asked, here is my retrofit builder with the HTTPInterceptor

```
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    client.interceptors().add(interceptor)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    this.service = retrofit.create(LoginResponse::class.java)
```

Comment: Can you paste the response JSON which is generated? Though I see this error is something wrong on the server-side and not android.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path)

Comment: I'm unable to make the interceptor works. 

`val client = OkHttpClient()

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        client.interceptors().add(interceptor)


        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

        this.service = retrofit.create(LoginRequest::class.java)`

Comment: Pl edit your question and add this details to it, so others can check and revert

Comment: Well I just made working the HttpInterceptor. I see the problem, it returns me an HTML page. This is the normal response when the auth request didn't work. 
Might be due to my @body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The issue was the password because it had backslashes and quotes inside of it.

Kotlin was doing a wrong parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `fun login` object like below one.

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/api/authentication/login")
    fun login(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Call<LoginResponse>
```

then create a `fun` like this

```
       fun makeGSONRequestBody(jsonObject: Any?): RequestBody {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), Gson().toJson(jsonObject))
    }
```

you need to pass your `User` object like below

```
private fun login() {
val user = User("test@gmail.com", "dsea2EcFI32\\\"af'xn")

this.service.login(makeGSONRequestBody(user)).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
        if (response.code() == 200) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        // TODO
        println(t.message)
    }
 })
}
```