# End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, kotlin, postman, retrofit

I got that error message: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

I am new in android.

There is something that I can get in postman as json but I can't get in android via retrofit2.

This is the function, that causes the problem

```
@GET("getRequestsByPassenger/{id}")
    suspend fun getRequestsByPassenger(
        @Path("id") id: Int
    ) : List<ServiceRequest>
```

This is the Retrofit2:

```
private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            var request = chain.request()

            if (!token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)
                    .build()
            }

            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

    val INSTANCE: Api by lazy {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }
```

I am looking that problem the whole day. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
This is more than likely an issue with gson formatting your network request, make sure it is correctly formatted

> Gson is expecting your JSON string to begin with an object opening
> brace. e.g.
>
> {
>
> But the string you have passed to it starts with an open quotes
>
> "

Explanation

This sounds like an issue with GSON parsing your network request

This link shows how this exact issue can be created and has a post to how how to resolve
[Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path)

> Now, if you add this to your retrofit, it gives you another error:
>
> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>
> This is
> another well-known error you can find answer here (this error means
> that your server response is not well-formatted);
>
> So change server
> response to return something:
>
> {
> android:[
> { ver:"1.5", name:"Cupcace", api:"Api Level 3" }
> ...
> ] }

This answer leads you to another answer
["Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Which is the issue that i am expected to see

> Gson is expecting your JSON string to begin with an object opening
> brace. e.g.
>
> { But the string you have passed to it starts with an open quotes
>
> "