# I can't get the JSON data "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

This my Json

```
{
"teams": [
    {
        "idTeam": "133604",
        "idSoccerXML": "9",
        "idAPIfootball": "42",
        "intLoved": "4",
        "strTeam": "Arsenal",
        "strTeamShort": "ARS",
        "strAlternate": "Arsenal Football Club",
        "intFormedYear": "1892",
        "strSport": "Soccer",
        "strLeague": "English Premier League",
        "idLeague": "4328",
        "strLeague2": "UEFA Europa League",
        "idLeague2": "4481",
        "strLeague3": "FA Cup",
        "idLeague3": "4482",
        "strLeague4": "EFL Cup",
        "idLeague4": "4570",
        "strLeague5": "FA Community Shield",
        "idLeague5": "4571",
        "strLeague6": "",
        "idLeague6": null,
        "strLeague7": "",
        "idLeague7": null,
        "strDivision": null,
        "strManager": "",
        "strStadium": "Emirates Stadium",
        "strKeywords": "Gunners, Gooners",
        "strRSS": "https://www.allarsenal.com/feed/",
        "strStadiumLocation": "Holloway, London",
        "intStadiumCapacity": "60338",
        "strWebsite": "www.arsenal.com",
        "strFacebook": "www.facebook.com/Arsenal",
        "strTwitter": "twitter.com/arsenal",
        "strInstagram": "instagram.com/arsenal",
        "strDescriptionIL": null,
        "strDescriptionPL": null,
        "strGender": "Male",
        "strCountry": "England",
        "strTeamBadge": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/badge/uyhbfe1612467038.png",
        "strTeamJersey": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/jersey/mpintc1586884343.png",
        "strTeamLogo": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/logo/q2mxlz1512644512.png",
        "strTeamFanart1": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/fanart/xyusxr1419347566.jpg",
        "strTeamFanart2": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/fanart/qttspr1419347612.jpg",
        "strTeamFanart3": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/fanart/uwssqx1420884450.jpg",
        "strTeamFanart4": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/fanart/qtprsw1420884964.jpg",
        "strTeamBanner": "https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/team/banner/rtpsrr1419351049.jpg",
        "strYoutube": "www.youtube.com/user/ArsenalTour",
        "strLocked": "unlocked"
    }]}
```

This is my ApiService

```
public interface TeamApiService {


@GET("search_all_teams.php?l=English%20Premier%20League")
Observable<List<TeamModel.Team>> getTeam();
```

}

This is my Repository

```
 public class Repository {

private TeamApiService apiService;

@Inject
public Repository(TeamApiService apiService){
    this.apiService = apiService;
}
public Observable<List<TeamModel.Team>> getTeam(){
    return apiService.getTeam();
}
```

}

This is my "View Model"

```
public class SoccerViewModel extends ViewModel {

private static final String TAG = "ViewModel";
private MutableLiveData<List<TeamModel.Team>> teamList = new MutableLiveData<>();

private Repository repository;

@ViewModelInject
public SoccerViewModel(Repository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public LiveData<List<TeamModel.Team>> getTeamList() {
    return teamList;
}

public void getTeams() {
    repository.getTeam()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> teamList.setValue(result),
                    error -> Log.e(TAG, "getTips: " + error.getMessage()));
}}
```

This my View

```
private void observeData() {
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SoccerViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getTeams();
    viewModel.getTeamList().observe(this, new Observer<List<TeamModel.Team>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<TeamModel.Team> pokemons) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: " + pokemons.size() );
            initRecyclerView(pokemons);
            adapter.updateList(pokemons);
        }
    });
}

private void initRecyclerView(List<TeamModel.Team> team) {
   recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.teamRV);
   rv = new LinearLayoutManager(TeamView.this,RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rv);
   adapter = new TeamAdapte(TeamView.this,team);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

This is my Model

```
public class TeamModel {
@SerializedName("teams")
@Expose
private List<Team> teams = null;

public class Team {

    @SerializedName("idTeam")
    @Expose
    private String idTeam;
    @SerializedName("idSoccerXML")
    @Expose
    private String idSoccerXML;
    @SerializedName("idAPIfootball")
    @Expose
    private String idAPIfootball;
    @SerializedName("intLoved")
    @Expose
    private String intLoved;
    @SerializedName("strTeam")
    @Expose
    private String strTeam;
    @SerializedName("strTeamShort")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamShort;
    @SerializedName("strAlternate")
    @Expose
    private String strAlternate;
    @SerializedName("intFormedYear")
    @Expose
    private String intFormedYear;
    @SerializedName("strSport")
    @Expose
    private String strSport;
    @SerializedName("strLeague")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague;
    @SerializedName("idLeague")
    @Expose
    private String idLeague;
    @SerializedName("strLeague2")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague2;
    @SerializedName("idLeague2")
    @Expose
    private String idLeague2;
    @SerializedName("strLeague3")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague3;
    @SerializedName("idLeague3")
    @Expose
    private String idLeague3;
    @SerializedName("strLeague4")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague4;
    @SerializedName("idLeague4")
    @Expose
    private String idLeague4;
    @SerializedName("strLeague5")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague5;
    @SerializedName("idLeague5")
    @Expose
    private String idLeague5;
    @SerializedName("strLeague6")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague6;
    @SerializedName("idLeague6")
    @Expose
    private Object idLeague6;
    @SerializedName("strLeague7")
    @Expose
    private String strLeague7;
    @SerializedName("idLeague7")
    @Expose
    private Object idLeague7;
    @SerializedName("strDivision")
    @Expose
    private Object strDivision;
    @SerializedName("strManager")
    @Expose
    private String strManager;
    @SerializedName("strStadium")
    @Expose
    private String strStadium;
    @SerializedName("strKeywords")
    @Expose
    private String strKeywords;
    @SerializedName("strRSS")
    @Expose
    private String strRSS;
    @SerializedName("strStadiumThumb")
    @Expose
    private String strStadiumThumb;
    @SerializedName("strStadiumDescription")
    @Expose
    private String strStadiumDescription;
    @SerializedName("strStadiumLocation")
    @Expose
    private String strStadiumLocation;
    @SerializedName("intStadiumCapacity")
    @Expose
    private String intStadiumCapacity;
    @SerializedName("strWebsite")
    @Expose
    private String strWebsite;
    @SerializedName("strFacebook")
    @Expose
    private String strFacebook;
    @SerializedName("strTwitter")
    @Expose
    private String strTwitter;
    @SerializedName("strInstagram")
    @Expose
    private String strInstagram;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionEN")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionEN;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionDE")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionDE;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionFR")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionFR;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionCN")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionCN;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionIT")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionIT;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionJP")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionJP;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionRU")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionRU;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionES")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionES;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionPT")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionPT;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionSE")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionSE;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionNL")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionNL;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionHU")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionHU;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionNO")
    @Expose
    private String strDescriptionNO;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionIL")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionIL;
    @SerializedName("strDescriptionPL")
    @Expose
    private Object strDescriptionPL;
    @SerializedName("strGender")
    @Expose
    private String strGender;
    @SerializedName("strCountry")
    @Expose
    private String strCountry;
    @SerializedName("strTeamBadge")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamBadge;
    @SerializedName("strTeamJersey")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamJersey;
    @SerializedName("strTeamLogo")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamLogo;
    @SerializedName("strTeamFanart1")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamFanart1;
    @SerializedName("strTeamFanart2")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamFanart2;
    @SerializedName("strTeamFanart3")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamFanart3;
    @SerializedName("strTeamFanart4")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamFanart4;
    @SerializedName("strTeamBanner")
    @Expose
    private String strTeamBanner;
    @SerializedName("strYoutube")
    @Expose
    private String strYoutube;
    @SerializedName("strLocked")
    @Expose
    private String strLocked;

    public Team(String idTeam, String idSoccerXML, String idAPIfootball, String intLoved, String strTeam, String strTeamShort, String strAlternate, String intFormedYear, String strSport, String strLeague, String idLeague, String strLeague2, String idLeague2, String strLeague3, String idLeague3, String strLeague4, String idLeague4, String strLeague5, String idLeague5, String strLeague6, Object idLeague6, String strLeague7, Object idLeague7, Object strDivision, String strManager, String strStadium, String strKeywords, String strRSS, String strStadiumThumb, String strStadiumDescription, String strStadiumLocation, String intStadiumCapacity, String strWebsite, String strFacebook, String strTwitter, String strInstagram, String strDescriptionEN, String strDescriptionDE, String strDescriptionFR, Object strDescriptionCN, String strDescriptionIT, String strDescriptionJP, String strDescriptionRU, String strDescriptionES, String strDescriptionPT, Object strDescriptionSE, Object strDescriptionNL, Object strDescriptionHU, String strDescriptionNO, Object strDescriptionIL, Object strDescriptionPL, String strGender, String strCountry, String strTeamBadge, String strTeamJersey, String strTeamLogo, String strTeamFanart1, String strTeamFanart2, String strTeamFanart3, String strTeamFanart4, String strTeamBanner, String strYoutube, String strLocked) {
        this.idTeam = idTeam;
        this.idSoccerXML = idSoccerXML;
        this.idAPIfootball = idAPIfootball;
        this.intLoved = intLoved;
        this.strTeam = strTeam;
        this.strTeamShort = strTeamShort;
        this.strAlternate = strAlternate;
        this.intFormedYear = intFormedYear;
        this.strSport = strSport;
        this.strLeague = strLeague;
        this.idLeague = idLeague;
        this.strLeague2 = strLeague2;
        this.idLeague2 = idLeague2;
        this.strLeague3 = strLeague3;
        this.idLeague3 = idLeague3;
        this.strLeague4 = strLeague4;
        this.idLeague4 = idLeague4;
        this.strLeague5 = strLeague5;
        this.idLeague5 = idLeague5;
        this.strLeague6 = strLeague6;
        this.idLeague6 = idLeague6;
        this.strLeague7 = strLeague7;
        this.idLeague7 = idLeague7;
        this.strDivision = strDivision;
        this.strManager = strManager;
        this.strStadium = strStadium;
        this.strKeywords = strKeywords;
        this.strRSS = strRSS;
        this.strStadiumThumb = strStadiumThumb;
        this.strStadiumDescription = strStadiumDescription;
        this.strStadiumLocation = strStadiumLocation;
        this.intStadiumCapacity = intStadiumCapacity;
        this.strWebsite = strWebsite;
        this.strFacebook = strFacebook;
        this.strTwitter = strTwitter;
        this.strInstagram = strInstagram;
        this.strDescriptionEN = strDescriptionEN;
        this.strDescriptionDE = strDescriptionDE;
        this.strDescriptionFR = strDescriptionFR;
        this.strDescriptionCN = strDescriptionCN;
        this.strDescriptionIT = strDescriptionIT;
        this.strDescriptionJP = strDescriptionJP;
        this.strDescriptionRU = strDescriptionRU;
        this.strDescriptionES = strDescriptionES;
        this.strDescriptionPT = strDescriptionPT;
        this.strDescriptionSE = strDescriptionSE;
        this.strDescriptionNL = strDescriptionNL;
        this.strDescriptionHU = strDescriptionHU;
        this.strDescriptionNO = strDescriptionNO;
        this.strDescriptionIL = strDescriptionIL;
        this.strDescriptionPL = strDescriptionPL;
        this.strGender = strGender;
        this.strCountry = strCountry;
        this.strTeamBadge = strTeamBadge;
        this.strTeamJersey = strTeamJersey;
        this.strTeamLogo = strTeamLogo;
        this.strTeamFanart1 = strTeamFanart1;
        this.strTeamFanart2 = strTeamFanart2;
        this.strTeamFanart3 = strTeamFanart3;
        this.strTeamFanart4 = strTeamFanart4;
        this.strTeamBanner = strTeamBanner;
        this.strYoutube = strYoutube;
        this.strLocked = strLocked;
    }

    public String getIdTeam() {
        return idTeam;
    }

    public String getIdSoccerXML() {
        return idSoccerXML;
    }

    public String getIdAPIfootball() {
        return idAPIfootball;
    }

    public String getIntLoved() {
        return intLoved;
    }

    public String getStrTeam() {
        return strTeam;
    }

    public String getStrTeamShort() {
        return strTeamShort;
    }

    public String getStrAlternate() {
        return strAlternate;
    }

    public String getIntFormedYear() {
        return intFormedYear;
    }

    public String getStrSport() {
        return strSport;
    }

    public String getStrLeague() {
        return strLeague;
    }

    public String getIdLeague() {
        return idLeague;
    }

    public String getStrLeague2() {
        return strLeague2;
    }

    public String getIdLeague2() {
        return idLeague2;
    }

    public String getStrLeague3() {
        return strLeague3;
    }

    public String getIdLeague3() {
        return idLeague3;
    }

    public String getStrLeague4() {
        return strLeague4;
    }

    public String getIdLeague4() {
        return idLeague4;
    }

    public String getStrLeague5() {
        return strLeague5;
    }

    public String getIdLeague5() {
        return idLeague5;
    }

    public String getStrLeague6() {
        return strLeague6;
    }

    public Object getIdLeague6() {
        return idLeague6;
    }

    public String getStrLeague7() {
        return strLeague7;
    }

    public Object getIdLeague7() {
        return idLeague7;
    }

    public Object getStrDivision() {
        return strDivision;
    }

    public String getStrManager() {
        return strManager;
    }

    public String getStrStadium() {
        return strStadium;
    }

    public String getStrKeywords() {
        return strKeywords;
    }

    public String getStrRSS() {
        return strRSS;
    }

    public String getStrStadiumThumb() {
        return strStadiumThumb;
    }

    public String getStrStadiumDescription() {
        return strStadiumDescription;
    }

    public String getStrStadiumLocation() {
        return strStadiumLocation;
    }

    public String getIntStadiumCapacity() {
        return intStadiumCapacity;
    }

    public String getStrWebsite() {
        return strWebsite;
    }

    public String getStrFacebook() {
        return strFacebook;
    }

    public String getStrTwitter() {
        return strTwitter;
    }

    public String getStrInstagram() {
        return strInstagram;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionEN() {
        return strDescriptionEN;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionDE() {
        return strDescriptionDE;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionFR() {
        return strDescriptionFR;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionCN() {
        return strDescriptionCN;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionIT() {
        return strDescriptionIT;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionJP() {
        return strDescriptionJP;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionRU() {
        return strDescriptionRU;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionES() {
        return strDescriptionES;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionPT() {
        return strDescriptionPT;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionSE() {
        return strDescriptionSE;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionNL() {
        return strDescriptionNL;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionHU() {
        return strDescriptionHU;
    }

    public String getStrDescriptionNO() {
        return strDescriptionNO;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionIL() {
        return strDescriptionIL;
    }

    public Object getStrDescriptionPL() {
        return strDescriptionPL;
    }

    public String getStrGender() {
        return strGender;
    }

    public String getStrCountry() {
        return strCountry;
    }

    public String getStrTeamBadge() {
        return strTeamBadge;
    }

    public String getStrTeamJersey() {
        return strTeamJersey;
    }

    public String getStrTeamLogo() {
        return strTeamLogo;
    }

    public String getStrTeamFanart1() {
        return strTeamFanart1;
    }

    public String getStrTeamFanart2() {
        return strTeamFanart2;
    }

    public String getStrTeamFanart3() {
        return strTeamFanart3;
    }

    public String getStrTeamFanart4() {
        return strTeamFanart4;
    }

    public String getStrTeamBanner() {
        return strTeamBanner;
    }

    public String getStrYoutube() {
        return strYoutube;
    }

    public String getStrLocked() {
        return strLocked;
    }
}

public TeamModel(List<Team> teams) {
    this.teams = teams;
}}
```

I use https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to construct my Model. I still have this issue `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`. I'm using retrofit and rxjava in this project and Observable for call. can you enlighten me on this problem.

Comment: can you show TeamModel.Team class.

Comment: I update it bro.

Comment: I want to see the call of this data are you using retrofit or volley post some code

Comment: @UsamaAltaf i include it in my View Model class. please see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it tell you your json start with object but your model start with array ,
see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path) and note of that , it help you

change your code as below this :

```
public class temsData{

  private String idTeam;
  private String idSoccerXML;
  private String idAPIfootball;

       public String getidTeam() {
            return idTeam;
        }

    public String getidSoccerXML() {
            return idSoccerXML;
        }

    public String getidAPIfootball() {
            return idAPIfootball;
        }

// and add your more data like this ...

}
```

then made another class like this :

```
public class TeamList {

        private List<temsData> teams;
        public List<temsData> getTems() {
            return teams;
        }

}
```

then use TeamList class in your retrofit body to get your data

Comment: how should I fix it?

Comment: Ok bro i will try this

Comment: how should i pass the data from TeamList to Teamsdata? for my adapter

Comment: this is another question and you should ask this in another post , please accept my answer

Comment: Okay bro.. i will post another one. thanks