# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am getting this error when I try to add data to a database with retrofit and I don't know why.

Error:

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Service:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://invazoras-g5-back-desa.herokuapp.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


final HerokuService service = retrofit.create(HerokuService.class);
```

Call:

```
User user = new User (name, email, password, habilitated, moderator);
Call<User > call = service.create(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User >() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<User > call, Response<User > response) {
          User newUser= response.body();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User"+newUser +"created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<User > call, Throwable t) {
           t.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will be getting this error before what ever json your Heroku server is returning isnt formatted correctly. Can you provide a copy of the ouput json?

Comment: @Zachary I'm not getting any output because the method called is already onFailure, but idon't know how the user get's registrated on the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you recieving this error when building your project - check `google-services.json` file. In my case it contained a comment left from previous developer which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.setLenient()` if you have a `GsonBuilder` somewhere. This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20231009041009/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path) might help you.